# Loading feature module from another Angular4 project

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, module, load

This is regarding Angular4 project setup.

Is it possible to load the feature module from another Angular4 project?

The approach I am trying was to keep the project repositories separate and load feature modules conditionally into the main project. So that the development will be isolated and independent.
Any insights into this or is there any other better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should pull it out and create separate library then include (i don't now how yet) it in both project, for example like Angular Material 2.

I think when you create separate project with only this feature module and then export it in app module you can then install it with npm and import in many projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried an approach creating the applications using nx.
ref: https://nrwl.io/nx/guide-getting-started

The library provides a set of code that you can import and use to simplify common patterns and functionality in the Angular applications.